# Bad performance with multiple html pages in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, knockout.js, cordova

I was told that if you use multiple pages this will hurt performance because every html file opens in a separate browser windows.

Is this true? I use jquery and knockout.

Comment: You should take a look at [Steroids.js](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids), might help you solve your problem.

Comment: thank you i will be seeing steroids.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the more you have open at once, the more memory you app will take up and it will degrade performance. However, 3 pages doesn't seem like an awful lot.

Facebook used to use web views for their app and it started to slow down after you stacked 10+ views on top of eachother.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, is there any way to close these browsers when you change page